# Robomongo connection with Meteor mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nitrousio, robo3t

I have connected my localhost mongodb from robomongo but having problem in connecting Meteor mongodb.

I am running Meteor from nitrousio not on localhost.

In robomongo connection settings, it is showing "Connected to 'meteor_url:3001'. Authorization failed". I am using correct db in Authentication tab and nothing in username and password. Is this the root cause? If yes, what is the default username and pwd of mongodb? If no, then what should i do?

Comment: this is save my life . Good Question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I set the Robomongo (v 0.8.4) connection to use localhost (127.0.0.1) and port 3001. Everything else is empty/default. I am using Windows 7 btw. I was originally put on the wrong track as many references said to use port 27017 or 27018. Changing to 3001 worked for me.

My Robomongo settings:

[image: Connection tab]
[image: Authentication tab]
[image: Advanced tab]
[image: SSL tab]
[image: SSH tab]

Answer (score 0):

@Spiralis
it works on robomongo version 1.0 in linux also Thanks.

Just create new connection
and put 
`Name = Meteor`
`Address = Localhost`
`Port = 3001`
Done!