# Robomongo & Meteor mongodb localhost connection failure

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-connection, robo3t

I have a Meteor app running on localhost:3000.

Trying to connect to it with Robomongo results in "Authorization skipped by you" failure.

[image].

My settings are identical to the ones posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524884/1162235), so I didn't touch any of the other config tabs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. Can you save the connection and connect to Mongo?

Comment: Yes bizarrely enough, now it works. Testing fails, but exiting the edit dialogue and connecting from the main panel works.

Comment: There is obviously some kind of authorization. Skipping it does not solve the problem for me. On connection attempt : Cannot connect to MongoDB, error: Unable to connect to MongoDb

Answer (score 0):

First Save the connection in Robomongo

- please make sure that your project is run in the local host .
- and open the Robomongo GUI tool and open the save connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the file /etc/mongodb.conf, and configure with that information.

In my case, i bad wrote the mongodb port, and corrected this and it worked.

The default port is 27017

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't connect Robomongo with your meteor app but just with the MongoDB itself.

```
Default address is: localhost
Default port: 27017
```

Authentication is not needed

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you have entered a correct ip address. I have enterd an incorrect ip was getting same responce.

Answer (score -1):

Edit

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment in

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

save.

Restart service:

```
service mongod restart
```

**You are done.**

Comment: Do not EVER comment out bind_ip = 127.0.0.1!!!!! You can add other IPs to it, but if you comment out bind_ip you are creating a potential security vulnerability allowing public access to your mongodb server. See mongodb security checklist here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#limit-network-exposure